# Asymptote-LaTeX: Evince not displaying coordinate axes in plots

Tags: asymptote, coordinates, evince

I was using asymptote in order to do some plot I needed and in stand alone it all seem to work. The code is:

```
import graph; 
size(10cm);

scale(Linear,Linear(-1));

typedef real realfcn(real); 
realfcn F(int p) { 
return new real(real x) {return -1/x*log(exp(x)*cosh(x*p)+sqrt(exp(2*x)*cosh(x*p)^2-2*sinh(2*x)));}; 
}; 

for(int i=0; i < 6; ++i)
draw(graph(F(i),0.001,10),Pen(i),"$h={"+((string) i)+"}$");

xlimits(0,10,Crop);
ylimits(-10,0,Crop);

xaxis("$\beta$",BottomTop,0,10,LeftTicks); 
yaxis(Label("$f_{\Lambda}$",BeginPoint,W),BottomTop,-10,0,LeftTicks); 

attach(legend(2),(point(S).x,truepoint(S).y),10S,UnFill);
```

and the correct output is correct: [image: 1]

However when passing to pdfLaTeX the output no longer shows the coordinate axes:
[image: 1]

How can I solve this problem? Thank you

There was only a problem in the Evince PDF viewer, with other PDF viewer like Okular or Acrobat it works fine. Still I don't know how to get it right in the PDF viewer without changing it.

Comment: I don't understand. Apart from fonts, both outputs look similar...?

Comment: yes, I checked only with Evince and now with another pdfreader works fine... I think is just a problem in visualization...

Comment: If it's only a viewer problem, what you can do is preparing a minimal example and do a bug report to the developers. I don't think there's much that can be done on the TeX side.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a PDF viewer problem

Comment: I am trying to understand if there is something to on the TeX side, but maybe you are right and this is a pure problem of the viewer, in this case we may delete this question